# JPA no respeta tamaño de columna de tipo VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, db2

Estoy probando almacenar una cadena encriptada en **DB2** que puede tener una longitud de hasta **8000** caracteres, si hago el INSERT directamente en el manejador funciona correctamente,  el problema está cuando se intenta insertar un registro desde la aplicación, el error que me marca indica que la cadena excede el tamaño permitido pero la cadena solo tiene 280 caracteres.

El campo fue declarado la siguiente manera:

```
ENCRYPTED_DATA VARCHAR(8000) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL,
```

Y en JAVA se consume con un @ColumnTransformer

```
@ColumnTransformer(
    forColumn = "ENCRYPTED_DATA",
    read = "DECRYPT_CHAR(ENCRYPTED_DATA, 'PASSS')",
    write = "ENCRYPT(?, 'PASS')")
  @Column(name = "ENCRYPTED_DATA", length = 8000, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(8000) FOR BIT DATA")
  private String encryptedData;
```

Si se quita la etiqueta @ColumnTransformer, el error con el tamaño desaparece.

Comment: que driver y version de JDBC estas utilizando para conectarte a As400/DB2?

Comment: Estaba usando el driver de DB2, la solución fue actualizar el driver utilizado en la aplicación para que coincidiera con la versión de DB2 instalada en el server